# Mobile Safari media query issues

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari, responsive-design, media-queries

So I'm trying to do a basic phone number swap so the number is clickable on mobile but not desktop.

I've been working with the following code (mostly targets iphone):

CSS

```
#phone .mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (min-device-width: 320px) {

    #phone .mobile {
        display: inline;
    }

    #phone .desktop {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

in head (used from h5bp)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Chrome and opera mini work fine but Safari is displaying BOTH numbers.
I notice Safari makes all phone numbers clickable. Could this be something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with some javascript/jquery

1) check the window width
2) if this is more than a certain amount of pixel, then you can output a link without href, otherwise add your tel:39000000 or whatever :)

Ciao
Fabio

Comment: That's a good idea of a work-around but what if I run into this issue with another responsive element?

Comment: The more elements run into this issue, then more probably you should consider two different apps, one for mobile and one for desktop. To create a universal solution only makes sense if you have the same content (obviously different CSS). But if you start having more than a couple of exceptions, well, there is nothing to do I suppose... it's against the idea of universal apps...

Comment: It's not my call to make that decision. Our site is not yet mobile optimized with the exception of the phone number.
I've tried the javascript solution but now Chrome on iPhone is not triggering the check for window size of less than or equal to 640. What gives?